# Python Speech Recognition Program Tends To Hang In A Certain Place

Tags: windows, python-3.x, debugging, speech-recognition

This program is not complete but is a work in progress.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess as sp
import time, os
r = sr.Recognizer()
print("Voice Recognition Software\n\n******************************************************************************\n")

while True:
    r.energy_threshold = 8000
    t = None
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        success = False
        print (">")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("Processing...")
            t = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print (": " + t)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Unknown input") 
            continue
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("An error occured at GAPI\nA common cause is lack of internet connection")
            continue

        if "open" in t:
            t = t.replace("open","")
            t = t.replace(" ","")
            t = t + ".exe"
            print (t)

            for a,d,f in os.walk("C:\\"):
                for files in f:
                    if files == t.lower() or files == t.capitalize() or files == t.upper():
                        pat = os.path.join(a,files)
                        print (pat)
                        sp.call([pat])
                        success = True

        if success == True:
            continue
```

The problem I'm facing is that after `>` or `Processing` the program sometimes stops responding. No error messages or anything, in the shell it just prints `>` or `Processing` and stays there.

This happens randomly, the program can function continuously for a long time but at any given moment for whatever reason it freezes. Usually after a minute or 2 it moves onto the next part and starts responding again but that isn't always the case.

I've attempted to create a sort of fail-safe so if it takes too long to respond the program closes and opens again but I was unsuccessful with that so now I'm trying to figure out the root cause of the problem.

Can someone with experience with this sort of thing help me understand why this is happening?

Edit:

I was able to solve the problem. Turns out there is a timeout parameter here `r.listen(source)`.

Comment: If you have an answer it is better to put it in answers, not in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Turns out there is a timeout parameter here `r.listen(source)`.